# How to configure Request Tracker on Debian and generate tickets?

Tags: linux, debian

I'm following [Installing Request Tracker 4 on Debian](http://burn.co.nz/blog/?p=54) but got stuck in email configuration. 
I got mail server configured properly and it is working fine. 
I need to configure the `Request Tracker` for incoming and outgoing mails

Description: 
Got mail server installed as like `iredmail`, now trying to install and configure `RT` on top of the existing mail server & so did I. `RT` is available at `localhost/rt` Now I'm having hard time to configure `RT` for the purpose it servers.

Comment: Please describe more specifically the problem you are having.

Comment: @[Faheem Mitha](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4671/faheem-mitha): I just edited my question! If you need any more info please tell me what exactly do you need so I can help you out with the proper info. Thanks!

Comment: @Neel is it the RT configuration you need help with, or the local mailer alias?

Comment: @[roaima](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/100397/roaima)  I need help with `RT` configuration.

Comment: Neel, you really need to give more detail. Tell us what you tried to do, and then what happened. Include all relevant details, including version numbers.

Comment: Well as I mentioned there is already a working  mail server (solution like `iRedMail` existing. I have installed `RT` in the same machine. Now I need all the mails to `helpdesk@domain.lcl` to come to the `Request Tracker` but I'm not understanding how to do that.
`RT version 4.0` `Debian version 7.8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
helpdesk:         "|/usr/bin/rt-mailgate --queue 'Helpdesk' --action correspond --url http://localhost/rt"
```

in `/etc/aliases` and now receiving mails which are designated to helpdesk@doamin.lcl in `RT`